# Bootstrap form spacing issues with form-inline and form-group?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

So I'm trying to create a basic layout for someone to enter their name and address, and it currently looks something like:

[image]

So, I'm basically stacking like this:

```
<div className='form-inline'></div>
<div className='form-group'></div>
<div className='form-inline'></div>
```

But why is there a space between the `'form-group'` and the `'form-inline'`? Is there anything I can do to take it out?

To do this, I used this structure:

```
          <form action="" className="form-inline">
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input
                            className="form-control"
                            placeholder="First Name"
                            }}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div action="" className="form-group">
                        <input
                            className="form-control"
                            placeholder="Last Name"
                        />
                    </div>
                </form>
                <form action="" className="form-group">
                    <input
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder='Street'
                    />
                </form>
                <form action="" className="form-inline">
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input
                            className="form-control"
                            placeholder='City'
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input
                            className="form-control"
                            name='state'
                            placeholder='State'
                            maxLength='2'
                            size='2'
                            type='text' 
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input
                            className="form-control"
                            name='zip'
                            type='text'
                            placeholder='zip'
                            maxLength='5'
                            size='5'
                        />
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as I'm new to bootstrap, thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.form-group` has `margin-bottom: 15px;` defined, but if the `.form-group` element is defined inside the `.form-inline`, it has no margin applied.

Demonstration:

```
<div class="form-group"></div> <!-- margin-bottom: 15px -->

<div class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group"></div> <!-- margin-bottom: 0 -->
</div>
```

So use `.form-group` inside `.form-inline`

```
<div class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ocean800 If this helps you, please accept the answer.

Comment: I'm not allowed to accept yet as you answered quickly, will be accepting in 3 min!

Comment: @ocean800 Hahah... No problem. Its my pleasure!